# Workaround for applying a mask to an image in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I have a function that accepts an image and rounds it, like so:

```
    public static Image roundImage(Image img) {
    int width = img.getWidth();
    Image roundMask = Image.createImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 0xff000000);
    Graphics gr = roundMask.getGraphics();
    gr.setColor(0xffffff);
    gr.fillArc(0, 0, width, width, 0, 360);
    Object mask = roundMask.createMask();
    img = img.applyMask(mask);
    return img;
}
```

This works great for images, but if I pass `FontImage` to it, the function throws an exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported Operation`. How can I check whether masking is a supported operation? I want to avoid changing the application logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FontImage` is a `requiresDrawImage` which is unique. You can convert it to a regular image or even to an encoded image using `toImage()` or `toEncodedImage()` respectively.

For this use case a regular image will be better/faster so `toImage()` should work best.